# Excel Misaligned Timestamps

Tags: excel

**[Edited]**

I have a Excel workbook (.xlsx) with two worksheets (Sheet 1 & Sheet 2).  Sheet 1 has 7 columns of data (each with about 70k rows) while Sheet 2 only has 5 columns with about 250-500 rows. The first column of each sheet contains a timestamp of when the data was collected in the format (yyyy-mm-dd_hh:mm:ss).

The discrepancy is that the data in Sheet 1 has data points spaced at 8 second intervals. Sheet 2, however, has sporadic data entries.  There might be 4 or 5 entries that happen in a burst (say 5 second interval) and then not another entry for another couple of hours.

What I'd like to do is reorganize Sheet 2 so that the timestamps align with Sheet 1.  The reason for this is that when I graph the data in sheet 1, the visualization looks appropriate because the data is evenly spaced throughout.  However, I can not graph the data in Sheet 2 the same way because the data points occur at sporadic intervals.

I'm comfortable in C# and considering trying to create a program which will read in a csv file of each sheet and do the batch processing... but even there I'm a bit stuck as to what the proper procedure would be.  Is there a way this can be handled directly in Excel?  Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the timestamps in Sheet2 ***has*** a match in Sheet1, regardless if the intervals are sporadic, yes? :)

Comment: Actually, to complicate things... no, the timestamps in Sheet2 does not match Sheet1.  They are in the same format, but the timestamp might fall within the 8 second interval and not match exactly.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Say we've got timestamp A and C in Sheet1. B in Sheet2 falls inside the 8 seconds between A and C. What is your expected result of B, match the row of A or match the row of C in Sheet2?

Comment: I guess match B with whichever timestamp is closest... although it's not entirely critical... because I can live with the fact that since there are over 70k datapoints, it wont have a major impact on the data if timestamp B nudges one way or the other by a few seconds.

Comment: So all the 5 columns of data in Sheet2 are dates, yes? And it's not important to keep the 5 column format if multiple dates fall inside two dates in Sheet1, so long as they're on the proper row, yes?

Comment: Actually, just the first column in both sheets contain the timestamps.  the other columns contain other data attributes, but not necessarily dates.  So, ideally I just want to move all of the data on a given row in sheet2 to match the same approximate row in sheet1 (according to the timestamp).  Hopefully that is clear.  Your point is a good one, in that there are times where there are multiple entries in sheet2 which might fall within one time interval in sheet1.  For instance, there might be 3 or 4 entries all of which occurred within 8 seconds... so all of those might match the criteria.

Comment: Regarding the multiple entries in sheet2 which might fall within a single interval in sheet1... I'm not entirely sure what the right protocol would be in this situation.  I guess it would be ok if only the entry that occurred closest to the timestamp in sheet1 was retained, while the others are just deleted.  I'm open to suggestions.  It seems to be quite a complicated problem :)

Comment: Having one column of 200-300 timestamps in Sheet2 makes this a whole lot faster affair, but I'm having personal issues with the multiple matches. Based on my experience in data analysis, deleting one node is not good, even if you're data is big. Might cause normality or somesuch to skew in favor of another statistic. By any chance, can you edit your post to display what you're attempting to create in the big picture? Why the need to match specific row in Sheet1? Perhaps there's another way? :)

Comment: Yes, it does. So the only question now is, what to do with multiple matches. Lol. I'm trying to get only the closest one for now, instead of all. Is it safe to assume that the list of dates in Sheet2 is sorted ascendingly?

Comment: Yes.  Both sheets have ascending timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of background. I tested this on three sheets. First sheet has 100k dates with 8-second intervals. Second sheet, I have 5 columns of 300 data points, with first column containing the dates with sporadic intervals. I've decided against mangling the second sheet so my output is in a third sheet for testing purposes.

Our logic is locating the largest value that's smaller than our target date. This way, we're inside the 8 seconds between this located date and the next one. We then get that value's row from the first sheet, then we use that row as the same row number in our results sheet. We then "transfer" the values from the second sheet to the proper row in the results sheet.

Runtime is negligible on my machine. Hopefully, this runs for you properly as well. ***Kindly test on a copy of your workbook.***

```
Sub Align()
    Dim RefWS As Worksheet, ListWS As Worksheet, ResWS As Worksheet
    Dim RngOne As Range, RngTwo As Range
    Dim RngVal As Variant, Elem As Variant
    Dim LRowOne As Long, LRowTwo As Long, LRowThree As Long
    Dim LocRow As Long, RowCt As Long
    Dim PopRng As Range, StartRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set RefWS = .Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as necessary.
        Set ListWS = .Sheets("Sheet2") 'Modify as necessary.
        Set ResWS = .Sheets("Sheet3") 'Modify as necessary.
    End With

    LRowOne = RefWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LRowTwo = ListWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Make sure to change based on whether you have headers or not.
    Set RngOne = RefWS.Range("A1:A" & LRowOne) 'Modify as necessary.
    Set RngTwo = ListWS.Range("A1:A" & LRowTwo) 'Modify as necessary.

    RngVal = RngTwo.Value
    'Change RowCt to 2 if you have headers.
    RowCt = 1

    For Each Elem In RngVal
        LocRow = Application.Match(CDbl(Elem), RngOne, 1)
        ResWS.Range("A" & LocRow & ":E" & LocRow).Value = ListWS.Range("A" & RowCt & ":E" & RowCt).Value
        RowCt = RowCt + 1
    Next Elem

    'Autopopulate.
    With ResWS
        LRowThree = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Do
        StartRow = .Range("A" & LRowThree).End(xlUp).Row
        If StartRow > 1 Then StartRow = StartRow + 1
        Set PopRng = .Range("A" & StartRow & ":E" & LRowThree)
        .Range("A" & LRowThree & ":E" & LRowThree).Copy
        PopRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        LRowThree = StartRow - 1
        Loop Until StartRow = 1
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

It's also important to note that if two values are matched, it's going to get the *latest* value rather than the closest one. Let me know first what happens to your data after running this.

**EDIT:** Code updated as per chat.

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I created a macro called 'Align' and copied the code you provided.  When I run the macro, I get an error: "Run-time Error:13: Type Mismatch".  When, I try to debug... the highlighted line is LocRow = Application.Match(CDbl(Elem), RngOne, 1) however, I'm not entirely sure what the error might be.  Thoughts?

Comment: Run it again. While the erroneous line is highlighted, kindly hover your mouse over `Elem`. Wait for the tooltip to appear. It should show a value. What is it? Alternatively, while the line is highlighted, type this into the immediate window: `?Elem`.

Comment: Ok.  When I hover over Elem, the tooltip shows, "Elem="2014-02-10_13:57:58".  Is it because it thinks it's a string and not a date?

Comment: Yes, it is. I forgot about the `_`. Is it possible to remove those or do you want it kept that way?

Comment: I can remove it... but should I replace it with a space?  Or how should I handle the underscore?

Comment: Just replacing it with a space should be fine. I'm thinking of incorporating it into the code as well later on, depending on how it runs for you on your end. I assumed that the format for both columns was **Date**. Sorry about that.

Comment: No, that's ok... it was my mistake.  I removed the underscore and the cell now appears to be a date.  I've done this on both sheets.  I then run the macro... but nothing happens.  Do I have to select some of the cells?  Or is there something else I'm forgetting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47796/discussion-between-bk201-and-andyopayne)